# Как сделать чтобы бот реагировал на неизвестные команды Telebot Python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Мне нужно, чтобы бот при наборе неизвестной команды/фразы выдавал сообщение в духе "Я вас не понимаю". Саму реализацию данной команды я понимаю, но проблема в том, что он выводит ее на каждый текст, даже когда этого не нужно. Как можно реализовать такую функцию только в рамках левого текста, чтобы во время введения нужных мне данных с клавиатуры в бота он не писал "Я вас не понимаю"?

Comment: Вы же не думаете, что мы можем помочь вам без кода? Быть может, вопрос нужно [edit] и добавить код?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Делаешь хендлер без фильтра - туда будет все сыпаться, что не попало в другие хендлеры. Если нужно только команды, то в фильтр хендлера пишешь "все, что начинается на /"

Comment: @Глеб А зачем вам код? Чтобы описать, как нужно сделать данную программу, он вовсе не обязателен

Comment: @CausonQ Спасибо, посмотрю попробую сделать

Comment: @Mark95ツ, чтобы на основе вашего неправильного кода можно было сделать правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы неизвестные команды были обработаны тебе нужно расположить методы, или роутеры с методами так, чтобы реализация метода для всех остальных случаев была самая последняя.

Comment: При чем тут интерпретируемость питона? Если бы он был компилируемым, ничего бы от этого не изменилось.